# Generating quiz questions randomly from a file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I'm just practising in Python and have an issue, I'm trying to generate a quiz from a text file which will ask a random question from the file.

It is supposed to read the question then list the answers, separating them with the commas in the file which did work before trying to randomise.

At the moment it is just reading the first character of the line then display error "list index out of range" when trying to print "detail[1]". For example if it picks line 3 in the text file, will read "C" then when inputting will come up with the error.

Text file is below:

```
A,What is 1+1?,1,2,3,4,b,
B,What is 2+2?,1,2,3,4,d,
C,What is 3+3?,2,4,6,8,c,
D,What is 4+4?,4,8,12,18,b,
E,What is 6+6?,18,12,10,9,b,
F,What is 1+2?,1,2,3,4,c,
G,What is 5+5?,5,6,7,10,d,
H,What is 2*2?,2,4,6,8,b,
```

Code is below:

```
import random
class question:
def rand_line(fname):
        lines = open(fname).read().splitlines()
        return random.choice(lines)

file = rand_line("questions.txt")

for line in file:
    detail = line.split(",")
    print(detail[0])
    input()
    print(detail[1])
    print("a: ", detail[2])
    print("b: ", detail[3])
    print("c: ", detail[4])
    print("d: ", detail[5])
    print("Select A, B, C or D: ")
    select = input()
    if select == detail[6]:
        print("correct!")
    else:
        print("incorrect")
```

Comment: Take a look at `file` before your loop. What does it contain? Then look at the loop itself: `for line in file`. Does that still make sense? What value does `line` have within the loop?

Comment: Change `random.choice(...` to `random.choices(...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a line that is throwing you off:

`file = rand_line("questions.txt")`

You call it file, but really its just a random line in the file that looks like this:

`C,What is 3+3?,2,4,6,8,c,`

And when you do a `split(',')` your `detail` is only

`['C']`

I think you are wanting to have that line be a list/array. To do that, surround your `rand_line` with square brackets `[]`

`file = [rand_line("questions.txt")]`

Which changes the above output to:

`['C,What is 3+3?,2,4,6,8,c,']`

Now when you do a `split(',')` your `detail` is

`['C', 'What is 3+3?', '2', '4', '6', '8', 'c', '']`

Not sure what the `input()` is doing between  `print(detail[0])` and `print(detail[1])`

Also, to avoid mixed inputs for your letter selection, It may be beneficial to change the case to what you know the answer is in the questions file:

```
  print("Select A, B, C or D: ")
    select = input().lower()
    if select == detail[6]:
```

Example:

The answer is in the file is `c` but you are prompting to enter `C`

Another thing to do would be to to remove the for loop. Since `file` is really just a single line:

```
  line = rand_line("questions.txt")

  detail = line.split(",")
  print(detail[0])
  print(detail[1])
  print("a: ", detail[2])
  print("b: ", detail[3])
  print("c: ", detail[4])
```

Comment: That's great thank you very much exactly what I needed. The input() was just me testing something as well as the first character in the line (probably should have removed these before posting). Changing the cases is also something I was going to add so thanks for that too.

Answer (score 0):

After testing it on my side, it seems that "input()" alone might not work. You are using "input" to store as a variable what the user writes, so you have to put it on a variable, which is not done automatically.

```
x = input('Write your answer : a, b, c or d')
```

I'm not sure at all the issue is actually here, this is just some try to help

Comment: What does this have to do with the "list index out of range" error OP mentioned in their question?

Comment: Well this can help him so I think it's worth mentionning it. As I said I'm absolutely not sure it's linked to his error, and that's just a try to help. I can close if you think it's inapropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer the input() was just me testing something earlier and probably should have removed that before posting. :)